# Is it possible to dynamically add members to PHP objects?

Tags: php

Is it possible to add to PHP objects on the fly? Say I have this code:

```
$foo = stdObject();
$foo->bar = 1337;
```

Is this valid PHP?

Comment: Your code would work if it said `$foo = new stdClass();` `stdClass` is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's technically not valid code. Try something like:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->bar = 1337;
var_dump($foo);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 2):

It is **valid** as long as you use valid class eg `stdClass` instead of `stdObject`:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->bar = 1337;
echo $foo->bar; // outputs 1337
```

**You had these problems:**

- Using `stdObject` instead of `stdClass`
- Not instantiating your object using `new` keyword

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The only problem in your code is that it's missing a `new` before calling `stdClass`, and you're using `stdObject`, but you mean `stdClass`

```
<?php
class A {
    public $foo = 1;
}  

$a = new A;
$b = $a;     // $a and $b are copies of the same identifier
             // ($a) = ($b) = <id>
$b->newProp = 2;
echo $a->newProp."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

```
$foo = stdObject();
```

This needs to be:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
```

Then it will work.